Extending a Ray Actor or make a subclass be a Ray Actor
Look at the code below:
class A:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(n=10)

Adding @ray.remote at the beginning of any class will result in typing errors:

If A becomes an actor, the line class B(A) will get Should be a type expression, but received "RemoteFunction"
If B becomes an actor, the line super(B, self) will get The class type should be the first argument in a "super" call, but received "RemoteFunction"

Does this mean we cannot incorporate OOP designs into ray actors?

What if you use the same method but without using decorator syntax? ray.remote(B) wouldn't shadow B. (Or just use no-args super().__init__(...), then it doesn't matter if it's shadowed.)

@jonrsharpe that works, thank you!
